# Java text filter

Tags: java, regex, string

For a project I need to develop een Java application which checks a string on multiple parts:

1. First a text check if the word contains a word of a specified list.
   Keep reminded that:

   - It is possible that the input can contain a word of the list but there can be spaces or special characters can be put in between characters to bypass the filter. In that case the filter needs to filter the word to.
   - It is possible that the word can be placed in another word. Then the word needs to be filtered if list the before and/or after filter is specified.
2. Second is filtering the text if it contains an ip address.
   Keep reminded that:

   - It is possible that the input can contain an ip where speciale characters or spaces are used to bypass the filter. In that case the filter needs to filter the ip address to.
3. As third is filtering web addresses from the text.
   Also here keep reminded that:

   - It is possible that the input can contain an web address where special characters or spaces are used to bypass the filter. In that case the filter needs to filter the web address to.

I tested some idea's with checking on spaces and speciale characters, but it cost a lot of work to proces the incoming text.

An example of what i tried:

```
public static boolean validateBericht(String msg) {
    return validateTransformedBericht(msg);
}

private static boolean validateTransformedBericht(String bericht) {
    if (bericht.length() != 0) {
        for (String woord : ChatControlList.getChatControlList()
                .getWoordenLijst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (bericht.length() - (woord.length() - 1)); i++) {
                if (i == 0 || inTekenLijst(bericht.charAt(i))) {
                    int index = 0;
                    for (int j = i; j < bericht.length(); j++) {
                        if (inTekenLijst(bericht.charAt(j))) {
                        } else if (bericht.charAt(j) == woord.charAt(index)) {
                            index++;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (index == woord.length()) {
                            if ((bericht.length() - 1) == j
                                    || inTekenLijst(bericht.charAt(index))) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean inTekenLijst(char teken) {
    for (String tekenUitLijst : ChatControlList.getChatControlList()
            .getSpecialeTekens()) {
        if (tekenUitLijst.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(teken))
                || String.valueOf(teken).equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Has someone any idea how to solve it on a good working solution?

Harm

Comment: Can you provide example strings and what matches you're trying to get?

Comment: Who could have an idea based on the hazy description you've provided? All I see from this that some tests on a String value need to be made. Yes, regex might be the way for a "good working solution".

Comment: The description is updated with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should create two methods:

- first to test if the String matches the searched word
- and the second one to test the type of an address.

Then you can use them like you want in your code.

1. Code to check if your String matches the searched word:

   ```
     String line = "the wor ld is wonderful";
     String search = "wor ld";
     String pattern = "(" + search + ")";

     Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

     Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

     if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
     } else {
       System.out.println("NO MATCH");
     }
   ```
2. Method that tests a given address and tells if it's an IP address; a Web address or an invalid address:

   ```
   public static String testAddress(String address) {
     if (address.matches("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$")) {
       return "IP Address";
     } else if (address.matches("^(http\\:\\/\\/|https\\:\\/\\/)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*\\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*$")) {
       return "Web address";
     } else {
       return "invalid input";
     }
   }
   ```

And this is a **[Working Ideone Test](http://ideone.com/XtBlSk)**.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you could strip out all of the special characters and spaces, e.g.

```
testString = origString.replaceAll("[- #$%]", "");    //Extend the regex to add your own special characters
```

...and then search for the words...

```
containsWord = testString.toLowerCase().contains(badWord);
```

Comment: I am going to test this. Looks like something i am looking for.